# Pass value from server side to client side in Next JS using getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm building a application using nextJS.
In server/index.ts, I have :

```
expressApp.get('/', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { query } = parsedUrl;
    let username: string | undefined;
    if (process.env.STAGE !== 'local') {
      username = getUsername(req)?.toString();
    }
    return nextApp.render(req, res, '/', {...query, loggedInUser: username});
  });
```

and in my home page (path is '/'), I auto direct to path '/pageone' by doing:

```
const Home = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    router.push('/pageone', undefined, { shallow: true });
  }, []);

  return <PageOne />;
};

Home.getInitialProps = async (ctx: NextPageContext): Promise<{ username : string | string[] }> => {
  const query = ctx.query;
  return {
    username: query.loggedInUser? query.loggedInUser : 'testUser'
  };
};

export default Home;
```

I need this username variable in every page I build, how can I pass it to every page(for example pageone)?

Comment: Depending on your needs, I’d recommend redux (next-redux-wrapper) or context. There are redux examples [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples). Please note that getInitialProps in a custom _app.js opts you out of automatic static optimizations and render blocks the entire app (users will be greeted with an empty page until the request had been resolved). As such, I’d recommend doing a single fetch request in componentDidMount, saving the result to redux/context and loading placeholder skeletons until the request resolves.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach this username variable to the [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.locals) which this is it's purpose.

Then access the res.locals of the `getInitialProps` ctx.

```
// server.ts

// this express middleware will attach username to res.locals.username;
expressApp.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.locals = res.locals || {};

  if (process.env.STAGE !== 'local') {
    res.locals.username = getUsername(req)?.toString();
  }
  next();
});

expressApp.get('/', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
  const {query} = parsedUrl;

  return nextApp.render(req, res, '/', query);
});
```

Then instead of passing this value to the client, as you did, you can [redirect](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.redirect) from server side within `getInitialProps`.

```
// Home.tsx

const Home = () => {
  return <PageOne />;
};

Home.getInitialProps = async ({res}: NextPageContext): Promise<{ username : string | string[] }> => {

  if(res.locals.username === 'bla') {
    return res.redirect(301, '/pageone');
    // -----------^ will redirect at server side.
  }
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a module that might help.

[Next Coke API](https://github.com/NxRoot/next-coke-api) allows **typed communication** between **client and server**:

**Server:**

```js
// define API methods
const routes = {
    getName: async (body) => {
        return "your name is " + body.name 
    }
}

// export types to the client
export type AppRoutes = typeof routes

// export nextCokeHandler
export default function handler(req, res) {
    return nextCokeHandler(req, res, routes)
}
```

**Client:**

```js
// define coke client
const { coke } = nextCokeClient<AppRoutes>()

// call API methods
coke.getName({ name: "John" }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
})
```